# How to remove all rpy2 packages?

Tags: python, rpy2

How can I remove all packages that I installed with rpy2 with anaconda? I have an error, and saw many times that it may be due to corrupted packages, so I want to remove them all to check it

Comment: What do you mean by "installed with rpy2"? RPy2 is a bridge between Python and R, not a package manager. You install packages with `conda`, `pip`, or through an R command.

Comment: It's Anaconda... can't you just create a clean environment and remove the broken one?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I removed rpy2 and installed it again, and now it works

Comment: Please consider writing an answer to your question, or deleting it. Otherwise, it will remain in the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: OK, I will write the answer

Answer (score 1):

I removed rpy2 and installed it again, and it solved my problem